# how to filter text then replace it with different text

Tags: html, css

In the contact page in website I have a phone number and I need to write a code to find the exact phone number and to change it with a different number

Here is my code

```html
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><b style="">Phon</b>e</h2>       </div>
    <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-071bea1 elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading is-mac" data-id="071bea1" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
                    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">888-299-1979</h2>        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: "...and to change it with a different number in css". What do you mean by "in css"?

Comment: @PedroLima i edit my question

Answer (score 1):

You can not filter for content in CSS (unfortunately). However there is a little gimmick. You can add content via an `attribute` and display it via a `pseudo-element`.

Like so:

```css
span[number]::after {
  content: attr(number);
}
```

```html
<span number="888-299-1979"></span>
```

And you can even "search" and "edit" it like so:

```css
/* "searches" the number */
[number="888-299-1979"]::after {

  /* changes the number */
  content: "xxx-xxx-xxxx";  
}
```

```html
<span number="888-299-1979"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want **CSS** to identify **phone number** from your website and then change the phone number with another phone number?

Believe or not CSS can't search for a phone number on your website. Whatever you do you need a selector in CSS.

Your code block with **added ID** to it:

```
 <h2 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default" id="phone-number">888-299-1979</h2>
```

**CSS:**

```
#phone-number {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#phone-number:after {
    visibility: visible;
    content: "123456789"; //your new phone number here
}
```

Or you can do same **without** using CSS but using **javascript** [**RECOMENDED**]:

```
document.getElementById("phone-number").innerHTML = "your_new_phone_number_here";
```

Comment: Both at the same time with relatively equal solutions. xD